# Even page numbers do not show in fancyhdr

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr, roman-numerals

**Problems:**

1. Even page numbers do not show up using `fancyhdr` package.
2. Page number are centered, but should be right on odd and left on even.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% FRONTMATTER
%
\newcommand{\frontmatterSU}{
    \frontmatter
    \pagestyle{fancy}{
        \fancyhf{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    }
}

% ABSTRACT 1
%
\newenvironment{abstract1} { 
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    \chapter{Abstract 1}
}

% ABSTRACT 2
%
\newenvironment{abstract2} { 
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    \chapter{Abstract 2}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatterSU

\setcounter{page}{12}

% Abstract -----------------------------------------------------

\begin{abstract1} % creates the abstract header in 1
    \blindtext[10]
\end{abstract1}

\begin{abstract2} % creates the abstract header in 2
    \blindtext[10]
\end{abstract2}

\end{document}
```

**Outputs:**

Centered roman numbers on odd page numbers, but empty on even page numbers.

**Desired output:**

Right roman numbers on odd page numbers, left roman numbers on even page numbers.

**UPDATE 1:**

Page numbers are visible on both odd/even pages in the center and in roman. But for some reason, there is a line in the head that I cannot I tried with `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` but does not seem to work. How is the horizontal line removed?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `\pagestyle{roman}` instead of `\pagestyle{empty}`? Another 'error' is that chapter start pages use `plain` style instead of the desired other one. The usage of `\newenvironment` is wrong as well

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the feedback, it's quite helpful. I have removed `\pagestyle{empty}` from both environments and the page number is visible now on both pages (but even page number are shown top-right now?). However, when I switched to `\pagestyle{roman}` in the `\newcommand` I got an error saying `Undefined control sequence`.

Comment: But your pagestyle asks for centered page numbers! `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` And you haven't defined a pagestyle called `roman`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want right numerals on odd pages and left on even ones, tell `fancydr`: what you are asking for is centered numerals on all pages:

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```

And what you want is

```
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
```

Since you have defined the pagestyle as `fancy` (not `roman`) that's what you have to use: if you ask for the `roman` pagestyle you will get an error, because it's not defined. (Note that it is the `\frontmatter` instruction that is making the numerals roman, not anything in your `fancyhdr` instruction.)

If you want the **first** page of the abstract to have the numbers set left, you will need to add `\thispagestyle{fancy}` to override the `plain` that would otherwise be selected.

You can't define new environments with two arguments. A new environment needs three arguments:

```
\newenvironment{name}{start-code}{end-code}
```

Edited to add: Your headrule problem is because you are calling your fancyheader instruction set inside an environment, and it's not making a global change to the command. Put the `\renewcommands` outside the environment.

Comment: Excellent and thank you for the educational instructions!

Comment: @kexxcream Edited because I'd forgotten to point out that if you want the *first* page of a chapter fancy you will need to specify that separately, because otherwise it will be set to plain.